# How to get a second ValueMember for a databound custom combobox

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple custom combobox that just has an added property "ValueMember2".

I have the combobox datasource added to a dataset

I can set the property in code just as I would the normal property "ValueMember"

```
cboRadioType.ValueMember = "ID"
cboRadioType.ValueMember2 = "FREQMIN"
cboRadioType.DisplayMember = "MODEL"
```

The normal ValueMember property will return the ID from the datasource
The new ValueMember2 property just returns the string "FREQMIN"

My custom combobox code is as followed:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class NewCBO
Inherits ComboBox
Dim vm2 As String
<Description("Gets/Sets the ValueMember2 of Control")>
Property ValueMember2() As String
    Get
        ValueMember2 = vm2
    End Get
Set(ByVal Value As String)
    vm2 = Value
End Set
End Property
End Class
```

What do I need to change my custom property to make it return the value from the connected datasource?  All searches have turned up is how to "display a ValueMember"

Comment: Probably better ways to do this, but could always use the actual value member to lookup the record in the data source and return the required value.

Comment: That does work too I guess. Was just trying to knock down the number of times I connect to the database.

Comment: Shouldn’t need another hit to the dB,  just use the combo data source

Comment: Ah, yes, duh, I get so wrapped up in it, I lose sight of the simple....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom `ComboBox` class that includes a fairly rigorous implementation of `ValueMember2` and `SelectedValue2` based on the existing implementations of `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue`:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ComboBoxEx
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private _valueMember2 As BindingMemberInfo

    Public Property ValueMember2 As String
        Get
            Return _valueMember2.BindingMember
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                value = String.Empty
            End If

            Dim bindingMemberInfo As New BindingMemberInfo(value)

            If bindingMemberInfo.Equals(_valueMember2) Then
                Return
            End If

            'This part is implemented in ValueMember but cannot be here because SetDataConnection is Private.
            'It may be possible to provide our own implement of SetDataConnection but that is not done here.
            'If DisplayMember.Length = 0 Then
            '    SetDataConnection(DataSource, bindingMemberInfo, False)
            'End If

            'This part is implemented in ValueMember but cannot be here because BindingMemberInfoInDataManager is Private.
            'It may be possible to provide our own implement of BindingMemberInfoInDataManager but that is not done here.
            'If DataManager IsNot Nothing AndAlso
            '   value <> String.Empty AndAlso
            '   Not BindingMemberInfoInDataManager(bindingMemberInfo) Then
            '    Throw New ArgumentException("...", NameOf(value))
            'End If

            _valueMember2 = bindingMemberInfo

            'A rigorous implementation should also include implementation of corresponding events.
            'OnValueMember2Changed(EventArgs.Empty)
            'OnSelectedValue2Changed(EventArgs.Empty)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SelectedValue2 As Object
        Get
            Return If(SelectedIndex <> -1 AndAlso DataManager IsNot Nothing,
                      FilterItemOnProperty(DataManager.List(SelectedIndex), _valueMember2.BindingField),
                      Nothing)
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            If DataManager Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            Dim bindingField = _valueMember2.BindingField

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingField) Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("...")
            End If

            'This part is implemented in ValueMember but cannot be here because DataManager.Find is Private.
            'SelectedIndex = DataManager.Find(DataManager.GetItemProperties().Find(bindingField, True), value, True)

            'The following replaces the call to DataManager.Find above.

            If value Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(value))
            End If

            Dim newSelectedIndex = -1
            Dim [property] = DataManager.GetItemProperties().Find(bindingField, True)

            If [property] IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim list=DataManager.List
                Dim bindingList = TryCast(list, IBindingList)

                If bindingList?.SupportsSearching Then
                    newSelectedIndex = bindingList.Find([property], value)
                Else
                    For i = 0 To list.Count - 1
                        Dim obj = list(i)

                        If value.Equals(obj) Then
                            newSelectedIndex = i

                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If

            SelectedIndex = newSelectedIndex
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

There are some notes in there that you ought to read. Also note that `ValueMember` has design-time support that `ValueMember2` lacks. It may not be difficult to use the same editor but I didn't look into that. It's also worth noting that `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` are implemented in `ListControl` and thus are inherited by `ListBox` too. You'd have to implement this code separately in a custom `ListBox`.

I tested that control with the following code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("DateOfBirth", GetType(Date))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add(1, "Peter", #1/1/2001#)
            .Add(2, "Paul", #2/2/2002#)
            .Add(3, "Mary", #3/3/2003#)
        End With

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table

        With ComboBoxEx1
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .ValueMember = "Id"
            .ValueMember2 = "DateOfBirth"
            .DataSource = BindingSource1
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show($"ID: {ComboBoxEx1.SelectedValue}; Date of Birth: {ComboBoxEx1.SelectedValue2}", ComboBoxEx1.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

It worked exactly as expected. The same code should also work for other data sources, e.g. a `List(Of T)`, although I didn't do any additional testing.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney. I will give that a shot.  The code I posted did in fact quit working for some reason.  It worked for about an hour. I don't know what I changed but couldn't get it to wok anymore.  I will give yours a try.

Comment: @mScientist, I think that your code only worked by accident. Like I said, you seemed to be combining the functionality of `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` into one property with a circular reference. Given that you MUST have two properties if you want it to work like the existing ones, I didn't bother to work out exactly how your code would break but I'm sure that it would.

Comment: Just tested your code.  Worked like a charm for what I wanted it to do.  I will study up on what you have done and try to understand it better.  Thank you!  I will mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me....

Comment: FYI, I have ReSharper installed and used it to view the original source of the `ListControl` class and the `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` properties in particular. You can find that source code online as Microsoft has made all the .NET Framework source code public. Be aware that it is written in C#, but you should still be able to understand it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just to post what I have found out.  Not sure if it the correct way but it works.

I added the following to my custom control:

```
Dim mds As New DataTable
```

then in the property I changed to this:

```
<Description("Gets/Sets the ValueMember2 of Control")>
Property ValueMember2() As String
    Get
        mds = Me.DataSource
        ValueMember2 = mds.Rows(Me.SelectedValue - 1).Item(vm2)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)

        vm2 = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

I'm not sure why I have to do the -1 but works like a charm.

In the normal code, instead of combobox.selectedvalue I just use combobox.ValueMember2 and it returns the proper item.

Comment: That code is an abomination. Firstly, it could only work with `Option Strict Off` and if the `DataSource` was a `DataTable`. Secondly, you seem to be mashing the functionality of `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` into a single property. The former is the name of the property or column that the `Selectedvalue` should be taken from and the latter is the actual value taken from that property or column of the `SelectedItem`. To do this properly, you would need to implement `ValueMember2` and `SelectedValue2` and to support any data source. I believe I can put something together to do that.